# Force ASP.NET controls to reload data

Tags: asp.net, viewstate, control-state

I know there's a lot of information out there about how disabling ViewState will not prevent textboxes from persisting values across refreshes/postbacks. What I can't fins is information about how to circumvent this behavior.

Here's why I need to do this. I have a form that updates a db via AJAX. Every time a user changes a field, the db is updated immediately. Because of this, there's no reason to store values anywhere but the database.

Consider the following scenario.

1. User loads the page, textbox FirstName has a value of "Bob."
2. User changes first name to "Dave." (Database updates)
3. User clicks the refresh button.

We'd expect the FirstName box to now have the value of "Dave," but instead it shows "Bob." So how to force ASP to load the values from the db?

Comment: The values ​​are only changed after a submit/postback information. You can use AJAX calls to do this without refresh.

Answer (score 1):

> User clicks the refresh button.

On this step you'd re-read the data from the database and forcibly populate the controls with that data.  If all of the "events" from the page are in fact handled by AJAX requests, then it sounds like the only two meaningful "WebForms events" are `Page_Load` and the `Click` handler for the "refresh" button.  One of those two events should re-populate the controls from the database.

(Or is there no "refresh" button and the user is just reloading the page via browser functionality?  In which case `Page_Load` should just always populate the controls from the database in this scenario.)

Comment: Ah ha. Problem was that I was populating in Page_Init, not Page_Load. Thanks!

Comment: An update on this. It seems to be working fine for "regular" controls, but not those that are created dynamically. I can verify in the codebehind that the correct values are being set for the dynamic controls, but these seem to be overridden somewhere along the way. Any thoughts?

Comment: @christok: Where are they being overridden?  There are a lot of things that happen to page controls throughout the WebForms page lifecycle.  This could potentially be enough to merit a new question, but at the very least merits updating the existing question with code to reproduce this observed behavior.

Comment: Thanks David - if you see my answer below, I've figured out what the problem is, although I can't explain why. I had been trying to set the control values at the same time I created them (in Page_Load). What I really needed to do was to split this up: create the controls in Init and set values in Load.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem I was encountering had to do with creating and populating controls in during the correct page events. Fixed this by creating controls in Page_Init, and populating them in Page_Load.

Comment: This order of events sounds a lot closer to what the engine internally does during the WebForms page lifecycle: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx  Essentially the Init stage is where the controls are being created, and the Load stage is where their properties are available to be set.